# Destroy leaflet map trouble

Tags: leaflet

I use several leaflet maps at one time. They can be created and deleted dynamically. But when a map is destroyed by using the map.remove() there is a memory leak. Detached DOM trees appears. You can see it in Chrome Dev Tools.

[Screenshot with a leak.](http://www.vladoblgaz.ru/patyi/screen.png)

Example function I use to recreate div and map:

```
var map, mapDiv;
recreateMap = function(){
    // destroy previous map and div
    if(map) map.remove();
    if(mapDiv) mapDiv.parentNode.removeChild(mapDiv);
    // create new map div
    var randomDivId = 'mapId' + new Date().getTime();
    mapDiv = document.createElement('div');
    mapDiv.id = randomDivId;
    mapDiv.style.height = '200px';
    mapDiv.style.width = '200px';
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(mapDiv);
    // attach map to div
    map = L.map(randomDivId).setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);  
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
    map.invalidateSize();
};
```

[Working example here.](http://www.vladoblgaz.ru/patyi/index.html)

How to properly destroy the leaflet maps?

Answer (score 10):

Assume you create a leaflet map with some thing like the following

```
var lat =39, long = 40;
var coords=[lat,long];
var zoomLevel=13;

var mapInstance = leafLet.map(mapContainerId).setView(coords, zoomLevel);
```

You can remove it using the following code

```
if (mapInstance && mapInstance.remove) {
  mapInstance.off();
  mapInstance.remove();
}
```

If you are working with non blocking javascript code or async calls, if required you can use a timer to ensure that your code does not error out. Following is a sample implementation of the same

```
var timeoutIndex=0;
var watcher=window.setInterval(function(){
  timeoutIndex++;
  if (mapInstance && mapInstance.remove) {
      mapInstance.off();
      mapInstance.remove();
      window.clearInterval(watcher);
  }
  if(timeoutIndex >50) {  //wait for 5 seconds before giving up
      window.clearInterval(watcher);
  }  
},100);
```

It worked for me. Guess it helps you too

Comment: thank you very much, the following code worked for me.
`code`
if (mapInstance && mapInstance.remove) {
  mapInstance.off();
  mapInstance.remove();
}

Answer (score 3):

If you have several maps, you need to put each map into diffents var.

```
var map1 = L.map(mapDiv1);
var map2 = L.map(mapDiv2);
```

You can also create a function to control map initialisation and container :

```
function BoolMapInit(map, mapDiv) {
    return (map != null && map._container.id == divMap);
}
```

And the fonction to remove existing map :

```
function RemoveExistingMap(map) {
    if (map != null) {
        map.remove();
        map = null;
    }
}
```

Hope this help ;)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and after spending much time on it, the best solution for this problem is to put the map container in a `div`, and when you want to regenerate the map, remove all of the `div`'s HTML and create a new map container:

```
<div id="map-bx">
   <div id="map"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Map init
</script>
```

and when you want to regenerate (destroy) the map like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#map-box").html(""); 
    $("#map-box").html('<div id="map"></div>');
    // map init code
</script>
```

in my case, `map.remove()` or `map.unload()` do not work.

Comment: This results in a blank map in my case not sure if it can work

Comment: @user3821178 best way is to remove all layers, then call remove method on map and then fill map variable by null

Comment: How can i remove all layers?

Comment: @user3821178  `map.eachLayer(function (layer) { map.removeLayer(layer); });`

Comment: Still working in 2022. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to `unload` map first? (documentation says that map is being unloaded automatically when using `remove` method but it's worth to give an additional shot and try unload it manually first)

Comment: unload function can no longer be called on a map instance